# htaccess rewrite. https to http url mask

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to mask a url for a domain that is `https://domainsecure.com/main/index.php`
To `http://domain/main/index.php` They are both pointing to the same directory, but I dont want to show the domainsecure I want to show the domain url when visiting the https domain, is that possible, by changing the htaccess.

Comment: At the same time leaving the connection encrypted?

Comment: I was hoping so, I realize this might not be possible, the client I am working for host has ssl installed on a shared domain, and we have setup a credit card proccess payment through stripe but they want the company domain in the url not the host shared domain that has ssl installed. I guess the alternative would be to setup there ssl, and not use there hosts shared one. But if possible not to that would be ideal.